Passing Data Between Components in Angular using a service with a RxJS subject
What I'm Trying To Do
I have two unrelated components in my Angular client app. The first component is responsible for fetching and processing data from the server. I'm trying to use the subscribe callback function to navigate to a new page and show a processed data (blob). To be more specific I want to go to a new tab and do a preview of the word document using an unrelated component. I found that it is possible to pass data through unrelated components using a service with a RxJS subject.
What I'm Getting
I've implemented some code, but a blob doesn't reach the preview component.
What I've tried
Here's some code I came up with:
Service for transferring a Blob object
@Injectable()
export class DocPreviewService {
  private blob = new BehaviorSubject<Blob | undefined>(undefined);
  public share$ = this.blob.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setBlob(blob: Blob) {
    this.blob.next(blob);
  }
}

Function responsible for retrieving the blob from the server (first component)
  showReport(selected_id: string) {
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([`tools/${selected_id}/preview`]));
    // it's important that the page opens in a new tab
    window.open(url, '_blank');

    this.report_service.createReport(this.calc_items[selected_id]).subscribe({
      next: (doc_blob: Blob) => {
        {          
          this.doc_preview_service.setBlob(doc_blob);
        }
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
      },
    })
  }

Component responsible for viewing a document (second component)
export class DocPreviewComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  doc_blob?: Blob;
  @ViewChild('doc_preview') doc_preview!: ElementRef;
  subscription: Subscription;
  
  constructor(private doc_preview_service: DocPreviewService, private local_storage: LocalStorageService) {
    this.subscription = this.doc_preview_service.share$.subscribe(blob => {
      this.doc_blob = blob;
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.doc_blob) {
      doc.renderAsync(this.doc_blob, this.doc_preview.nativeElement)
      .then(x => console.log("docx: finished"));
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Actually, the subject emitter method has the limitation that it only works for communication between unrelated components in a single tab, cross tab communication is not possible, because the service will have two separate instances in each tab, so the event is never received
To solve this scenario, all you need to do is append the API call params to the URL
Code opening the tab
  showReport(selected_id: string) {
    // basically we append the required param needed for making the API 
    // call, then we use it to call the blob logic on the other tab initialization!
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([`tools/${selected_id}/preview?id=${this.calc_items[selected_id]}`]));
    // it's important that the page opens in a new tab
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }

The component opening the blob will be
export class DocPreviewComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  doc_blob?: Blob;
  @ViewChild('doc_preview') doc_preview!: ElementRef;
  subscription: Subscription;
  
  constructor(private doc_preview_service: DocPreviewService, private local_storage: LocalStorageService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.report_service.createReport(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.id).subscribe({
         next: (doc_blob: Blob) => {
              this.doc_blob = doc_blob;
              if (this.doc_blob) {
                  doc.renderAsync(this.doc_blob, this.doc_preview.nativeElement)
                  .then(x => console.log("docx: finished"));
              }
         },
         error: (error: any) => {},
     })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

This above code might contain error, but I hope you take this approach and solve your issue!

You can try PostMessage API to transfer Blob object between tabs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
